# MEX C++ raw data access

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

I'm trying to access the raw data of a MATLAB matrix passed to a MEX C++ function based on the answer [here](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/436916-how-to-access-raw-data-via-the-mex-c-api). Strangely, I get a memory access error every time. How do I access the raw data?

```
void operator()(matlab::mex::ArgumentList outputs, matlab::mex::ArgumentList inputs)
{
    TypedArray<uint32_t> dataArray = std::move(inputs[0]);
    uint32_t* dataRaw = dataArray.release().get();

    for (auto& elem : dataArray)
    {
        elem *= 2; // Works
        uint32_t x = (*dataRaw); // Memory access error
        ++dataRaw;
    }
[...]
}
```

Comment: Why is the pointer `*dataRaw` in parenthesis where the code gets the "Memory access error"?

Comment: I prefer it that way, in case I change anything in that line. That way I know that the dereferencing doesn't get messed up.

Comment: The error happens in this line: uint32_t x = (*dataRaw); // Memory access error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by storing the pointer returned from the release() method explicitly. It seems that the data is lost otherwise.

```
TypedArray<uint32_t> dataArray = std::move(inputs[0]);
auto dataPtr = dataArray.release();
uint32_t* dataRaw = dataPtr.get();
```